# Mongo - Retain ordering based on the query params?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

How could I do the following in mongo?

```
db.questions.find( { _id: { $in: [ "506b422ff42c95000e000004", "506b422ff42c95000e00007a", "506b422ff42c95000e00008d"] } } ).sort( {_id: { $in: [ "506b422ff42c95000e00007a", "506b422ff42c95000e00008d", "506b422ff42c95000e000004"]}});
```

Is it even possible or do I have to do this on the code end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really. You'll need to do that yourself. The results won't come back in the order you construct your query. See this similar question: [Order of responses to MongoDB $in query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142260/order-of-responses-to-mongodb-in-query)

Your ID's do look numerically ordered though and they're based on date, so you could sort on _id itself, but there's no way of even determining if those objects would even be stored in that order in the database.