# MongoDB : find query with an OR condition with additional column to tag which conidtion the record correspond to

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to fetch certain records from a table using the following OR query

```
db.book.find({
    "$or" : [ 
        { "_id': ObjectId("53e49ab8fdc5c42d13965e85")},
        { "topics": { "$in" : ["mysql","MongoDB"] }} 
    ]
})
```

I need to tag the results in my final output to show where the record came from, i.e. did the record match first condition or the second one. How to do that ?

**EDIT:**

Posted solution (with help from Phillip)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does MongoDB's $in clause guarantee order?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22800784/2313887) At least in principle. Not closing yet without a clarification.

Comment: Why not have two queries then?

Comment: Because I don't want to check twice. If the first condition meets when I am executing find query, I want to tag it as 'id match' and if second condition is satisfied, I want to tag it as 'topic match'

Comment: Something like this in SQL Databases
`select *, case when id in (3,4,5) then 'id match' else 'topic match' end as tag 
from book where id = 3 or topic = 'Databases';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.tbook.aggregate(
{ 
   "$match": {
      "$or": [
        { "_id": ObjectId("53e49ab8fdc5c42d13965e85") },
        {"topics": { "$in" : ["mysql","MongoDB"]}} 
      ]
   } 
},
{ 
   "$project": { 
    "intersect": { 
        $setIntersection: [ "$topics", ["mysql","MongoDB"] ] 
     } 
   } 
},
{ 
   "$project": {
     foundBy: { 
        $cond: {
           if: { $eq : [ "$intersect", [] ] },
           then: "id match",
           else: "topic match"
        }
     }
   }
}
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) with the [`$cond` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) could help you here.

The first step of the aggregation would be a $match with the same object you have in your find above. The second step would then be a $project which uses the $cond operator to generate a new field `foundBy` which gets a different value depending on whether or not the _id of the document matches the one in the query.

```
$project: {
    // fields from original document you want to retain unchanged:
    any: 1,
    field: 1,
    you: 1,
    need: 1,
    // a new, computed field:
    foundBy: { 
        $cond: {
           if: {$eq: [ "$_id", ObjectId("53e49ab8fdc5c42d13965e85") ] },
           then: "id match",
           else: "topic match"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Phillip. Although one challenge though. I will be searching for an array of id's. $eq checks for equality. Is there any operator in $cond expression which is similar to $in ?

Comment: @mandeep_m91 Maybe one of the [set expressions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#set-expressions) can help you in this case. I haven't used these yet, so I unfortunately can't tell you more about them than you can read in the documentation.

Comment: It worked... Had to use two $project stages though..
Updated the solution in question.

Comment: @mandeep_m91 You might want to move the edit from your question to an own answer. Self-answering questions is encouraged on stackexchange.