# Keep the order of list used in $in query in Mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a query like below

```
    query = PhotoLocation.query.filter(photo_location_filters)
    photo_locations = yield query.find()
    id_list = [i.photo_id for i in photo_locations]

    photo_filters = {}
    photo_filters.update({'_id': {'$in': id_list}})
    photo_filters.update({
        "has_images": True,
        "is_hidden": {
            "$ne": True
                }
            })
    query = Photo.query.filter(photo_filters).limit(limit)
```

I lose the order of id_list after $in query. Is there a way to keep the order of id_list in query below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using `$in` - there's a feature request, [SERVER-7528](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7528), for it.

If you are using MongoDB version 2.4 or earlier, switching to `$or` will work:

```
db.filters.find({ "_id" : { "$in" : [1, 2, 3] } })
```

into

```
db.filters.find({ "$or" : [
    { "_id" : 1 },
    { "_id" : 2 },
    { "_id" : 3 }
] })
```

This no longer works in MongoDB 2.6.

Comment: I actually thought I posted a link to a [couple of working solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797768/does-mongodbs-in-clause-guarantee-order/22800784#22800784) in the comments of that issue some time back. That would seem better than just copying something from the issue that no longer works.