# grails-mongodb: findAllBy*InList not returning results in order

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.4

I'm using grails2.4.4 with mongodb plugin version 3.0.3. I'm facing issue while getting results of my domain object. I'm using below code:

### My domain:

```
Employee{
   ObjectId id
   String name
}
```

I have list of ids , using below code to fetch employees: (Please note that below data is just for representing my problem. In realtime, my ids are random and so i can't use sorting, but i just want the result in the order of input.)

```
def idsList=[new ObjectId("2001"), new ObjectId("2002"), new ObjectId("2003")]
def results=Employee.findAllByIdInList(idsList)
```

Expected result:

```
[Employee@2001,Employee@2002,Employee@2003]
```

Actual result (not in order):

```
[Employee@2002, Employee@2003 , Employee@2001] or sometimes
[Employee@2003, Employee@2001 , Employee@2002]
```

For now i'm doing like this to get the output in desired order:

```
def results=[]
for(id in idsList){
   def emp=Employee.findById(id)
results<<emp
}
```

But i want to do this with single call(findAllBy*InList) without iterating over objects. Can anyone advise how can i get the results in the order of input ids?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does MongoDB's $in clause guarantee order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797768/does-mongodbs-in-clause-guarantee-order)

Comment: To clarify that [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) is the operator applied to arguments to `*InList` methods.

Comment: Oh.. that means its the problem with underlying mongodb, not with either grails or mongodb plugin. In that case, the solution i was using is the only option for me to preserve the order as of now. Thank you very much for the link @BlakesSeven

Comment: As I said. The method constructs an `$in` query. The answer in the duplicate question shows server side ways of dealing with this. Otherwise sort your results after they are returned. It's not a MongoDB "problem", it's how it is meant to work.

Comment: Oh ok. I can't use sorting, as in my real time case ids are random and so i want the result in the order of input. I will update my question.

Comment: If you read the "duplicate questions" answer it explains all of that. "sorting" your results means "picking" the order of results due to the order of arguments you supplied them in. ie. Sort by the index order of your argument list.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are checking that. In the duplicate question link you provided, accepted answers and comments as well, says mongodb doesn't return the results in order of input you supply. I need to go by either Aggregate or mapReduce as explained in the link. But as im using grails (without underlying low-level api to access mongodb) can't go by either of the  approaches.

Comment: No it does not say that at all, it says the opposite *"As noted, the order of the arguments in the array of an $in clause does not reflect the order of how the documents are retrieved"*. That's the first sentence. The rest explains how to order by the order in which you supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
Employee.findAllByIdInList(idsList, [sort: 'id', order:'asc'])
```

? It should work as expected

If it doesn't, instead of `for` loop you can use

```
def result = idList.collect { id -> Employee.findById(id) }
```

Comment: Hi, your first solution sorts the objects by ids. I just given example for representation of my problem. In fact, i just want the result in the order of given input because in my real time case, ids are random. Your second solution approach is same as mine but in more groovy way. Anyways thanks for the suggestions :)

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear from the question (before the edit) that the ids are not in order. For the second point: In my opinion the `collect` is more readable and shorter so it comes close to your requirement. You can also use `Employee.get(id)` and that is even less characters :). Cheers!

Comment: Got it.  Will change my code as you suggested to make it more cleaner. Thank you :)