# change the order of mongoose result with the given array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am having Nodejs model,

```
itemModel.find({deleted:false},function(error,response){

  });
```

// here i am getting response,

```
[{_id:'3221xxx',status:"b"},
 {_id:'3221xxx',status:"a"},
 {_id:'3221xxx',status:"d"},
 {_id:'3221xxx',status:"c"}
]
```

// I have rule in array e.g:  `['a','b','c','d']` in this order, i have to list the data based on this array. like this,

```
[{_id:'3221xxx',status:"a"},
 {_id:'3221xxx',status:"b"},
 {_id:'3221xxx',status:"c"},
 {_id:'3221xxx',status:"d"}
]
```

Please help me the better & easy way

Comment: use [sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/) like this `find().sort({"status":-1})`

Comment: if the rule change in that array means this doesnt work ..eg. ['d',a'','c','d'].. this will not work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does MongoDB's $in clause guarantee order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797768/does-mongodbs-in-clause-guarantee-order)

Comment: use underscore: `_.sortBy(result,function(item){return ['c','b','a','d'].indexOf(item.status) })`