# How to query a batch of documents by IDs orderly

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to query a batch of documents by `ids` (the elements of it might be duplicate),  for example

```
var ids = [
  "57470bda627fe714555d96d1", "57470bda627fe714555d2401",             
  "57470bda627fe714555d9922" , "57470bda627fe714555d2401",
  "57470bda627fe714555d2401"
];

var results = db.collection('Person').find(query_containing_ids);

//The desired results
results = [{_id:"57470bda627fe714555d96d1", name:"xxxx"},
           {_id:"57470bda627fe714555d2401", name:"yyy"},
           {_id:"57470bda627fe714555d96d1", name:"xxxx"},
           {_id:"57470bda627fe714555d2401", name:"yyyy"},
           {_id:"57470bda627fe714555d2401", name:"yyyy"},]
```

The query results should be in the same order as `ids` and there might be duplicate objects in the results.

Is it that possible in Mongodb?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/

Comment: Looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797768/does-mongodbs-in-clause-guarantee-order