# MongoDB keep order with $in by using Async.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, async.js

Like you know `{$in: {_id: []}}` doesn't keep order.

I want to use Async.js for this purposes.

For example

```
const ids = [3,1,2]; // Initial ids, I get it from aggregation
const documents = [{_id:1}, {_id:2}, {_id: 3}]; // That's I get from MongoDB
const result = [{_id:3}, {_id: 1}, {_id: 2}] // That's I need
```

How can I perform this with Async.js? I'm using `mongoose.js` with [mongoose-fill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-fill) which don't work with `aggregation`

Comment: whats wrong with collecting all results and then using just JS sortBy any parameter that you like?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what did you mean.
Like I think, I have to write two loops:
    var result = [];
    for(var i=0;i<ids.length;++i)
        for(var j = 0; j < documents.length; ++j)
            if(ids[i] == documents[j]._id) {
                result.push(documents[j]._id);
                continue;
            }
Something like this?

Comment: Check my answer. Simple always better. Maybe i miss understand your question. But based on what i see you need to sort results of all queries. Which can be done just fine in JS. But if you want to query each id one by one and then sort array. I would recommend just use one query. This is increase performance by a lot.

Comment: I have already received documents from MongoDB, but order not match parameters. I want to sort documents exact the same as parameter array.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797768/does-mongodbs-in-clause-guarantee-order? Lots of options in the answers there.

Comment: @JohnnyHK thx, I found solution. Very appreciate..

Answer (score 1):

You dont need async here. Natural JavaScript sort will help you with this.

To query mongodb just use query like this

`{_id : {$in: [1,2,3]}} ;`

When you receive results like this

`const documents = [{_id:1}, {_id:2}, {_id: 3}];`

Now you can just run simple sort

`let result = documents.sort((a, b) => a._id < b._id);`

`console.log(result);`

Will output sort by id descending order.

`[{_id:3}, {_id: 2}, {_id: 1}];`

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, no, no.. I want to map documents with ids. Example with a post not correct. I found solution [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32385762/7054633)