# Mongodb mapReduce gives Mongoerror "Value is null"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mapreduce, mongodb-query

I am trying to understand mapReduce function, and using it to sort the response in same order as the array of ids provided, according to this [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797768/does-mongodbs-in-clause-guarantee-order). Everything works fine when i try to extract books by providing a Array of book titles, but using array of ids it doesn't work. I tried converting ids to ObjectIds but still no hopes.  following is data model for books.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const BookSchema = mongoose.Schema({

  title: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  },

  author: {
    type: 'string'
  },

  coverUrl: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  },

  owner: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  },

  description: {
    type: 'string'
  }

});

let Book = module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);
```

code for extracting data is,

```js
// booksIds is an array with only two ids which are strings. 
// three arguments passed to callback (err, docs, stats)

Book.getBooksByIdsWithOrder = function (booksIds, callback) {
  
  // let book_titles = ["The History of Street Art", "A Night In The Woods"];

  booksIds[0] = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(booksIds[0]);
  booksIds[1] = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(booksIds[1]);

  let ask = {}
  ask.map = function () {
    
    var order = inputs.indexOf(this._id);
    emit( order, { doc: this } );
  };
  
  ask.out = {"inline": 1};
  ask.query = { "_id": {"$in": booksIds}};
  ask.scope = {"inputs": booksIds};
  ask.finalize = function (key, value) {
    return value.doc;
  }
  
  Book.mapReduce(ask, callback);
};
```

Error!

```js
{ MongoError: TypeError: value is null :
@:2:5

    at Function.MongoError.create (/home/user/web_development/bookTradingClub/backend/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at /home/user/web_development/bookTradingClub/backend/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:497:72
    at authenticateStragglers (/home/user/web_development/bookTradingClub/backend/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:443:16)
    at Connection.messageHandler (/home/user/web_development/bookTradingClub/backend/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:477:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/user/web_development/bookTradingClub/backend/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:331:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'TypeError: value is null :\n@:2:5\n',
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'TypeError: value is null :\n@:2:5\n',
  code: 139,
  codeName: 'JSInterpreterFailure' }
```