# I am unable to preserve ordere when query $in in mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to query in mongo using the $in . however the result i see are not in same order as i had passed them .

```
var objectids = [
  "111",
  "222"
]
db.sample.aggregate([{$match:{someFields:{ $in: objectFieldIds }}}])
```

How the value return will be 222, 111.
How does this happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does MongoDB's $in clause guarantee order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797768/does-mongodbs-in-clause-guarantee-order)