# MongoDB $in operator

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose

I have a table with following values

```
[
{
   id: 1,
   name: "abc"
},
{
   id: 2,
   name: "lmn"
},
{
   id: 3,
   name: "xyz"
}
]
```

I have a query with $in as

```
{
  id: {
    $in: [ 2, 3, 1 ]
  }
}
```

i want the output to come like so:

```
[
{
  id: 2,
  name: "lmn"
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: "xyz"
},
{
  id: 1,
  name: "abc"
}
]
```

But it does not come like that. Is there a way I could achieve this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) stage, as $in does not preserve order.

There are quite a few questions on stackoverflow about this issue for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797768/does-mongodbs-in-clause-guarantee-order) question.