# How to retrieve multiple documents from mongodb ordered by a list of ids?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query

I have a collection in MongoDB in which I need to fetch multiple documents at a time but I would like them to be ordered based on the order of ids that I pass in. For example, if I pass in a list of ids: `[1, 5, 3]`, I want to receive the corresponding documents in that exact order: `[object with id 1, object with id 5, object with id 3]`.

I have tried using the `$in` operator but this typically returns documents ordered by when they were created. So if I created objects in the following order: `[object with id 1, object with id 3, object with id 5]` and I use the `$in` operator with the following ids: `[1, 5, 3]`, I still receive objects in the following order: `[object with id 1, object with id 3, and object with id 5]`.

Is there a way to do this in MongoDB?

Comment: The find query method returns a _cursor_. You can apply the [cursor#sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor.sort) on the `id` field.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42293303/19084052 you might interested in .it was useful for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does MongoDB's $in clause guarantee order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797768/does-mongodbs-in-clause-guarantee-order)