# Using mongoose.js is there a way to get a collection of documents in the same order of the ids that are in the array I pass them

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

For example I have a collection of these object Ids in the array below.........

```
let ids = [
  new ObjectId("628109759af30dbc4a27e130"),
  new ObjectId("6280f8edde998a4bebb58923"),
  new ObjectId("6280f8f3de998a4bebb5892d"),
  new ObjectId("6280f8f0de998a4bebb58928"),
]
```

when I pass them to this function below....

```
 let results =  Model.find({ _id: { $in: ids } }).exec()
```

I expect the results to be .......

```
let results = [
  {new ObjectId("628109759af30dbc4a27e130"), name:'model1'} ,
  {new ObjectId("6280f8edde998a4bebb58923"), name:'model2'},
  {new ObjectId("6280f8f3de998a4bebb5892d"), name:'model3'},
  {new ObjectId("6280f8f0de998a4bebb58928"), name:'model4'},
]
```

however , I end up with the results being ......

```
let results = [
  {new ObjectId("6280f8edde998a4bebb58923"), name:'model2'},
  {new ObjectId("628109759af30dbc4a27e130"), name:'model1'},
  {new ObjectId("6280f8f0de998a4bebb58928"), name:'model4'},
  {new ObjectId("6280f8f3de998a4bebb5892d"), name:'model3'},
]
```

The results are not in the same order as the ids in the original ids array I am passing to it.

Does anyone have an idea on how to get them in the correct order?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797768/does-mongodbs-in-clause-guarantee-order

Comment: Thats more mongo specific , im looking for a mongoose.js solution.

Comment: you can use aggregate in mongoose. and https://stackoverflow.com/a/32385762/13583510 if you dont want aggregate

Comment: thank you , I have not got the issue sorted with the non aggregate way =)