# Getting the documents in the specified order from MongoDB using C# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am new to MongoDB and I wanted to know whether it is possible to fetch the documents by Id in the order I have specified in the array. I am using official c# driver.

**Problem Description**

I have some documents in the collection like this

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "Name" : "Assignment 1"
}
```

to

```
{
    "_id" : "100",
    "Name" : "Assignment 100"
}
```

I have a array of Ids `{ "4", "19", "10", "6" }` and what I need is to fetch the documents specified in the same order as in the array.

These are the queries that I tried

> { "_id" : { "$in" : ["4", "19", "10", "6"] } }

```
{ "$or" : [{ "_id" : "4" }, { "_id" : "19" }, { "_id" : "10" }, { "_id" : "6" }] }
```

But both of these queries are returning the documents in the following order
[image]

But my expected result is

[image]

The only option in front of me right now is to make separate db requests for each elements in the array which I think is a bad option.

Can anyone of you please steer me on fetching the documents in the order that I have specified in the array. I am using MongoDB C# driver and expecting an answer based on C#.

Thanks,
Kapil

Comment: One more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142260/order-of-responses-to-mongodb-in-query

Comment: @NeilLunn: Thanks for directing me to that question, I wanted an answer in c# and your answer has helped me in achieving the same in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have finally managed to use the Aggregation framework to make this work.

This is the way I have achieved it. But I would be happy if somebody can suggest a better way than this.

```
string[] fetchingIds = { "4", "19", "10", "6" };

IMongoQuery fetchQuery = Query<Assignment>.In(x => x.Id, fetchingIds);
BsonDocument match = new BsonDocument { { "$match", fetchQuery.ToBsonDocument() } };

BsonDocument currentDocument = null;
BsonDocument finalDocument = null;
BsonValue processingDocument = null;
for (int i = 0; i < fetchingIds.Length; i++)
{
    BsonElement ifStatement = new BsonElement("$eq", new BsonArray(new[] { "$_id", fetchingIds[i] }));
    BsonArray conditionStatement = new BsonArray(new[] { new BsonDocument(ifStatement), BsonValue.Create(i + 1), -1 });
    currentDocument = new BsonDocument("$cond", conditionStatement);

    if (finalDocument == null)
    {
        finalDocument = currentDocument;
    }
    else
    {
        processingDocument = null;
        BsonValue tempDoc = finalDocument["$cond"][2] as BsonDocument;

        if (tempDoc == null)
        {
            processingDocument = finalDocument["$cond"];
        }

        while (tempDoc != null)
        {
            if ((tempDoc["$cond"][2] as BsonDocument) == null)
            {
                processingDocument = tempDoc["$cond"];
                tempDoc = null;
            }
            else
            {
                tempDoc = tempDoc["$cond"][2];
            }
        }

        processingDocument[2] = currentDocument;
    }
}


BsonDocument project = new BsonDocument { { "$project", new BsonDocument 
                                                        { 
                                                           // this will return whose document
                                                            {"obj","$$ROOT"},
                                                            {"weight",finalDocument},
                                                        } 
                                         } };

BsonDocument sort = new BsonDocument { { "$sort", new BsonDocument { { "weight", 1 } } } };

var result = assignmentCollection.Aggregate(new AggregateArgs
{
    Pipeline = new[] { match, project, sort },
}).ToList();
```