# mongodb query result sequence

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is my query statement.

```
db.users.find({"_id":{"$in":[id0, id1, id2]}})
```

Of course it will return correct user array, but the sequence is random, it could be

```
[user1, user0, user2]
```

or

```
[user2, user0, user1]
```

it depends on ids' value.

If there is a way that I could force mongodb always return user array like this

```
db.users.find({"_id":{"$in":[id0, id1, id2]}}) => [user0, user1, user2]
db.users.find({"_id":{"$in":[id1, id0, id2]}}) => [user1, user0, user2]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order of responses to MongoDB $in query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142260/order-of-responses-to-mongodb-in-query)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the query syntax supports that (I wouldn't think so), but you can always post-process the results to hash them by lookup id

Comment: That's how I handle query result now. Because I am not familiar with mongodb, so I wonder if there is a cool way to do it.